# Is it possible to import phone contacts book to a desktop app via Java?

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, windows

Is it possible to import phone contacts book to a desktop app via Java?

I have a phone connected to my laptop via USB, how can I do a phone contacts book import to the desktop app?

Android, IPhone, Windows and any other...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html <-- read phone contacts. so yeah its possible

Comment: Sure it possible. If you looking for all type of mobile then try to look some cross Platform technology for this. only java may not support you.Try this link http://developer.xamarin.com/